# spring webflow variable not updated with page refresh

Tags: spring-webflow

I have a situation in webflow. Where I navigate to the first page of flow after that I am loading all flow pages using the Ajax calls, which means everytime new page get loaded but the URL in browser address bar remains the same. So when user hit refresh, user routed back to first page of webflow.

"/Sample/dcTesting.page?**execution=e1s1**#DcHash1"

Now what I want to achieve is, when user click refresh I will check some value in flow using expression and instead of opening first page route to some other informational page.

How to do this?  Please guide

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide some guidance on this.

Comment: I tried creating a listener for flowexecution and inside requestProcessed method doing below after checking some condition but it is not redirecting to mentioned page.



aContext.getExternalContext().requestExternalRedirect("contextRelative:/showHome.page");